# Is there a name for the genre of poetry and song that treats what are ordinarily regarded as undesirable traits as if they were wonderful?

Tags: expressions, terminology

I’m thinking of Rodgers and Hart’s “I Wish I Were in Love Again,” Sondheim’s “Being Alive,” the song from Peter Pan “Who’s the swineiest swine in the world? Captain Hook!  Captain Hook!” and Shakespeare’s sonnet 130 “My mistress' eyes are nothing like the sun.”

Comment: parody, satire, lampoon

Answer (score -1):

This kind of absurd poetry can be called

> [**nonsense poetry**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nonsense_poetry)
>
> (Originally) whimsical or nonsensical verse;
>   (later) the ***genre*** of poetry that includes nonsense verse such as limericks, as well as looser poetic forms.

or

> [**nonsense verse**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nonsense_verse)
>
> Originally: nonsensical verse.
>   Later: whimsical or nonsensical verse intended to amuse by absurdity; an example of this, specifically a limerick; (in plural also) verses consisting of words arranged solely with reference to the metre and rhyme scheme, without regard to the sense.

Both definitions are from Lexico.